# Repeated data in DataBase

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I should read data from file Excel and save in my dataBase:

Class : CableServiceImpl

```
public class CableServiceImpl implements CableService{
private CableDao cableDao;
public CableDao getCableDao() {
    return cableDao;
                              }
public void setCableDao(CableDao cableDao) {
    this.cableDao = cableDao;
                                           }
public List<Cable> listeDesCables() {
    return cableDao.listeCable();
                                    }

public void creatCable(Cable wire) throws IOException {
    ServiceLectureExcel service = new ServiceLectureExcel();
    ArrayList<String> t = service.lectureCables();
    String tabCable[] = new String[t.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++){
        tabCable[i]=t.get(i);  
    }       
    for(int i=4;i<tabCable.length;i++){ 
        wire.setLeitung(tabCable[i]); 
        i++;    
        wire.setDq(tabCable[i]);
        i++;
        wire.setGrundfrabe(tabCable[i]);
        i++;
        wire.setKennfarbe(tabCable[i]);
        List<Cable> lisCable = cableDao.listeCable();

        if(lisCable.size()==0){ 
            cableDao.save(wire); 
            }
        else{
            cableDao.update(wire);
            }
    }

}
```

Problem : when i execute code more than once, my BD contain repeated data. so how can i solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you uniquelly and universally identify your row? (Example: a social security number, a GUID, etc). If so then create a log table in your database and for each imported row, mark the coresponding identifier as imported. If you don't have such an id then the only option is to compare field by field( like comparing a structure for equality in c#).But you also can do a trick here: instead of going directly to compare field by field you could compute a hash for each row and store it in db. Next time you import the row, compute first the hash code. If it is NOT present in yout hashes data table then for sure you can import it safelly. Otherwise you will fall back to the case of comparing your row with all rows already imported